# ImageUrl correct but image not showing in Gridview RSS

Tags: asp.net, database, image, linq, gridview

**My Database**
[image]

**Advertise.aspx**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hình ảnh">
       <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Image ID="imgHinhanh" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("adv_Url") %>' runat="server"></asp:Image>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Advertise.apsx.cs**

```
public void BindGrid() {
    grdAdver.DataSource = AdvertiseService.adv.Adver_GetAll();
    grdAdver.DataBind();
}
```

**AdvertiseService.cs**

```
public List<AdvertiseInfo> Adver_GetAll()
{
    return adv.Adver_GetAll();
}
```

**AdvertiseInfo.cs**

```
public partial class AdvertiseInfo
{
    public int adv_id { get; set; }
    public string adv_Name { get; set; }
    public string adv_Url { get; set; }
    public int? adv_Width { get; set; }
    public int? adv_Height { get; set; }
    public string adv_Link { get; set; }
    public int? adv_Target { get; set; }
    public int? adv_Position { get; set; }
    public int? adv_Order { get; set; }
    public int? adv_Status { get; set; }
}
```

Please help me. I wasted long time to fix but i can't. Thanks anyone.

Comment: adv.Adver_GetAll(); can you put this function. What image you are getting at browser end.

Comment: .jpg.jpg is not a correct image

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. But I want show you the screenshot.

Easiest way to debug is `View Source` and get the image Url.

[image]

Then copy and paste that Url inside your browser (if you use Chrome, you can click on it).

If image doesn't display, it is not in your file system or Url is not correct.

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply, my img tag is: 
<img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdAdver_imgHinhanh_0" src="../Images/Advertise/65512_428979943827007_925788477_n.jpg.jpg" />. It's still display image, but it can't display in gridview

Comment: Can you see this image in browser (copy & paste it to your browser, replace xxxxx with your testing port) `http://localhost:xxxxx/Images/Advertise/65512_428979943827007_925788477_n.jpg.jpg`? I just want to make sure because image extension itself is not well-formatted.

Comment: here bro, my src attr get here: http://localhost:49797/Images/Advertise/65512_428979943827007_925788477_n.jpg

Comment: I guess your actual file is `xxx.jpg`, but image in you database is stored as `xxx.jpg.j‌​pg`. Something is wrong.

Comment: i don't think so bro, because i changed my code but not effective.

Comment: Did you get chance to try the steps I posted in my original answer using chrome? **Do you see the image if you click on the image link inside `View page source`?**

Comment: it still display normal, i also check by Firebug. I really don't know why